# SBT - Assembly (Scala - Neo4j), How to deal with this deduplicate issue?

Tags: scala, neo4j, sbt, sbt-assembly

just trying to generate a Jar with sbt-assembly and I'm still trapped with this:

```
[error] (*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/fsalvador/.ivy2/cache/org.neo4j/neo4j-kernel/jars/neo4j-kernel-1.9.4.jar:META-INF/CHANGES.txt
[error] /Users/fsalvador/.ivy2/cache/org.neo4j/neo4j-lucene-index/jars/neo4j-lucene-index-1.9.4.jar:META-INF/CHANGES.txt
[error] /Users/fsalvador/.ivy2/cache/org.neo4j/neo4j-graph-algo/jars/neo4j-graph-algo-1.9.4.jar:META-INF/CHANGES.txt
[error] /Users/fsalvador/.ivy2/cache/org.neo4j/neo4j-udc/jars/neo4j-udc-1.9.4.jar:META-INF/CHANGES.txt
[error] /Users/fsalvador/.ivy2/cache/org.neo4j/neo4j-cypher/jars/neo4j-cypher-1.9.4.jar:META-INF/CHANGES.txt
[error] /Users/fsalvador/.ivy2/cache/org.neo4j/neo4j-jmx/jars/neo4j-jmx-1.9.4.jar:META-INF/CHANGES.txt
```

in my build.sbt I have tried the following:

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) => {
    case PathList("ivy2", "cache",  "org.neo4j", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case "CHANGES.txt"     => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => old(x)
  }
}
```

And still no joy, tried almost everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PathList(...)` extractor splits up the path string. The following should work:

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) => {
    case PathList("META-INF", "CHANGES.txt") => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => old(x)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Did you try a simpler:

```
mergeStrategy in assembly := mergeStrategy.first
```

*Update, don't do this, please see comments*

Comment: I specifically wrote in [README](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) *not* to do `mergeStrategy in assembly := mergeStrategy.first` because it's the wrong type, and because you'd be in a world of pain when you skip the default strategies that are necessary to make jar that works.

Comment: k, I guess I didn't look very hard. :) not sure whether to delete this or leave it for posterity.

Comment: I'd say delete it, and post a new answer if you come up with one.